# How to upload multiple videos at once with python YouTube Api

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I automated a youtube channel that sends memes from different social media platforms

Now , as I upload the videos , I need to authorise my app multiple times.

Is there a way, so I can upload 4,5 videos at once

It doesn't matter if the title and description are same

Thx in advance

Here's my code for upload

````
import datetime
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from apikey import apikey

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
credentials = flow.run_console()
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

upload_date_time = datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 25, 12, 30, 0).isoformat() + '.000Z'

request_body = {
    'snippet': {
        'categoryI': 19,
        'title': 'funny memes compilation 2022',
        'description': 'Upload TEsting This is Private Video',
        'tags': ['Python', 'Youtube API', 'Google']
    },
    'status': {
        'privacyStatus': 'private',
        'publishAt': upload_date_time,
        'selfDeclaredMadeForKids': False, 
    },
    'notifySubscribers': False
}

mediaFile = MediaFileUpload('1.avi')

response_upload = youtube.videos().insert(
    part='snippet,status',
    body=request_body,
    media_body=mediaFile
).execute()

"""
youtube.thumbnails().set(
    videoId=response_upload.get('id'),
    media_body=MediaFileUpload('thumbnail.png')
).execute()
""" ```
````

Answer (score 0):

To anwser your question The [Video.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) method is singular

> Uploads **a** video to YouTube and optionally sets the video's metadata.

Each video must be uploaded one at a time. You could create a loop in your  code to upload more then one but its still going to be 4 upload requests to the api

## batching method.

Most of the [google apis support batching](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/batch), however I have not be able to find any reference to the batching in the YOuTube data api though.   The only thing batching would save you really is the number of HTTP calls you are making its not going to save you the quota cost.  Im not really sure batching even supports upload tbh.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer !